How Can Computer Science Help a Content Creator’s Career?
My friend is in his second year of a Computer Science (CS) degree and also has strong content creation skills (video editing, design, etc.). He’s passionate about his creative work and wonders if CS skills could complement or enhance his content career.
Are there specific ways he could combine CS with content creation to improve his skills, career options, or efficiency?

Please find Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on? - I find your question off-topic here.

You can never know exactly when certain knowledge will be useful. If your friend has many different skills, it opens up different paths for him. If your friend doesn't know how to combine them, it's probably not the right time yet.
But one thing I am sure of is that well-developed creative skills allow him to be more creative in CS.
Sometimes, the ability to connect different skills comes with experience and time. As your friend continues to grow and explore, those skills will find their place, and the opportunities will become clearer.

Answer well-asked questions
